# Getting rid of open paths in Illustrator CS5 without overlapping stroked lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs5, stock-images

I have been looking into selling some vector art either by making my own site (almost doubles up as a portfolio) or sell it through existing stock vector sites. I am currently looking into requirements and condition they have before they will put the art on their website and most of my art meets all the conditions, except some websites won't allow art that has 'open paths'.

The reason this is a problem for me is because of they way or method I use for creating vector art.

First I draw out on paper my design and then scan it in to use as a template.
Then I stroke it all no fill just a black stroke. Then I proceed to colour the art (colour in the lines).
Then add whatever effect or final touches that particular piece may need.

The only open paths I have found in my work is when I stroke the scanned in sketch. I have tried to close them but the black stroke overlaps existing black strokes and then the line seems thicker in places? I need to find a way to close all my paths while not overlapping stroked lines again and again. The colour is all fine and closed just the black stroked lines.

Is there a way around this or is it just doing the previous method but executed more carefully, or by using pathfinder and compound paths or layering my files differently??

Just to clarify I am working in Illustrator CS5. I don't know if there is a certain workflow people use when making vector art with the hope of selling it or a checklist they have?? I am new at this so any help would be appreciated. my intention is to make easily editable vector art to anyone who buys it thats why I do the stroke and colour separately it adds a greater degree of control (at least thats how I feel).

Any help would be greatly appreciated because this is one of the last requirements I need to get vector art to a selling standard. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 99% of the cases, it's merely a matter of expanding the strokes via Object > Expand. This creates closed shapes rather than open, stroked, paths.

Selling vector files is not generally about selling edit ability. You are selling the art with the benefit of it being resolution independent, not necessarily editable.

If you are trying to "make a file as easily edited as possible" you are doing yourself a bit of a disservice. If someone can pay $x.xx for a file, then edit it, reuse it, pull parts of it, etc. forever, you have essentially put yourself into a disposable position. While offering full edit ability may seem like a good idea, in the long run if you intend to make a career out of such a venture, you may want to think about return customers.

***Side note:*** This is one reasons a 2-file workflow is generally best. One file left in tact, unexpanded for editing, then another file expanded and flattened for output when necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider some of the making the points you made will have a think about what is best.

Comment: My intention was to sell each piece of art at say, 3/4 pngs at varied sizes (as the size increases so does the price) then sell a EPS10 vector file which is scaleable but not editable ( bigger price increase) and then save the AI file down to CS2 OR CS3 and sell an editable file for an increased price. As someone who has sold vector art in the past do you think this is a good idea or method of selling or do you think I should just stick to one EPS10 file which is scaleable but editable??? A response would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for all the help.